# jquery toggle initially close help required

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I want help to close the toggle option when document is loaded, but if you try my current code you will notice that the #A is visible when page is loaded, also i tried all other ways to hide it but on every solution i used it automatically hides the toggle button/link please help me to find a way to initially close the toggle here is my code

html

```
<div id="A">SideBar</div>
<div id="B"><a href="javascript:" id="toggle">Toggle</a></div>
```

JavaScript

```
//Toggle Hide/Show sidebar slowy
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#B').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#A').toggle('');
        $('#B').toggleClass('extended-panel');  
        return false;  
    });
});
```

CSS

```
 #A, #B {
        position: absolute;
    }
    #A {
        top: 0px;
        width: 250px;
        bottom: 0px;
        background:#404041;
        z-index:999999;
    }
    #B {
        top: 0px;
        left: 250px;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0px;
    }

    /* makes the content take place of the SIDEBAR 
       which is empty when is hided */
    .extended-panel {
      left: 0px !important;
    }
```

Comment: How about adding `display: none;` to the `#A` rule?

Comment: nothing works for me properly it automatically hides the toggle button

Comment: It shouldn't, [a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/xsoxe3dc/). Notice, that you've to add the `.extended-panel` to `#B` in the HTML to "synchronize" the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but your question is a bit unclear.

Just call toggle on the #A on load.
Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshvito/x5kv4s3m/)
e.g.

```
//Toggle Hide/Show sidebar slowy
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#A').toggle();
    $('#B').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#A').toggle('');
        $('#B').toggleClass('extended-panel');  
        return false;  
    });
});
```

Comment: i think your fiddle link is not correct please check